# Help Identify this new to me touring bike

Tags: identify-this-bike

Just purchased locally.  Well outfitted.  Lugged steel frame.  27x1.25 tires.  Quick release front and rear, Center pull brakes. Shimano gears and brakes.  Serial number on the bottom of the head tube 7D02184  (nothing on the bottom bracket)
[image: whole bike]
[image: Searial on head tube][image: gearset]

Comment: Downtube (non-indexed) shifters, 27-inch tires make this a bike no newer than maybe 1988.  The nicely-lugged frame and other details indicate that it's a pretty decent quality bike.  The rack and fender lugs indicate that it was designed for touring.  But there's nothing distinctive to give you a brand.

Comment: First photo - are the fork tines/legs bent subtly backward, or is it an artifact of the photo and the slight turn of the wheel?   Might suggest a frontal impact at sometime in its past.

Comment: Shimano Deore derailleur and Biopace triple crankset ... yeah, late 80s, early 90s. That is some seriously low gearing there. Does that setup give you a 21-inch gear?

Comment: @Criggie: I'd check that fork, too! And the stem looks like pulled out beyond the limit. While turning the drops level will certainly improve access to the brake-levers.

Answer (score 1):

Im disclosing I may be very wrong here, I thought it was possibly an 1987 painted Schwinn Tempo but since the SN is on the headtube thats impossible and its more likely its a **1987 Schwinn Voyageur**. Im saying this mainly because of the Biospace crank sticker and Deore drivetrain and very similar features of the frame when comparing other pictures of this bike.

[image]

[image]

Comment: These look very similar and have the exact same components, but check the joint between seat stays and seat tube and the chainstay dent behind chainring.

Comment: The frame is slightly different where the seat post is brazed together and there is no dent behind the chainring.  I'll post more pictures.

Comment: @RDanPauley http://www.vintage-trek.com/images/trek/1987/87Trek12.jpg Possibly a 1987 trek cirrus 520 very similar to this bike I posted

Comment: Another family member who is into bikes thinks it is an '88 Panasonic PICS custom order (what ever that is) sent a picture and that looks exactly like it.  Bottom Line, it is too big for me the bike is a 25" frame, the seat post to head tube is 23"  As much as I'd like to ride it, I'm way out of ergonomics for this one.